# Sorting/ Filtering attributes not working in Grid.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, mvcgrid

The code for my Mvc Grid is shown below but for some reason the sortable and filterable attributes don't work as stated in the codePlex documentation. I am developing in .NET 4.5 using html5 and bootstrap.css:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Item2).Named("ViewEntries").Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryName).Titled("Entry Name").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryDate).Titled("Date").Sortable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryDetails).Titled("Details").Sortable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name1").RenderValueAs(c => Name1((int)c.name1)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name2").RenderValueAs(c => Name2((int)c.name2)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name3").RenderValueAs(c => Name3((int)c.name3)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                    }).WithPaging(10)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So the reason that this wasn't working was that gridmvc.css wasn't actually being referenced in the layout file in the first place. As soon as I added it, filtering works as intended on the normally rendered columns.

Now the problem I am having is getting filtering to work on columns that are rendered via a html helper but this just requires some research in to creating custom filterable widgets. Thanks for all the help guys =]

Comment: Hi, I did but in order to do this I ended up scrapping using html helpers. Instead I just re-designed my database a little and wrote a few more queries to pull exactly what I wanted into each Model. This negated the need to use html helpers and so I was able to just use the standard filters offered by the mvcgrid. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I came to the same conclusion myself and modified my view model.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as below

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Item2).Named("ViewEntries").Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryName).Titled("Entry Name").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryDate).Titled("Date").Sortable(true);
                        columns.Add(c => c.entryDetails).Titled("Details").Sortable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name1").RenderValueAs(c => Name1((int)c.name1)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name2").RenderValueAs(c => Name2((int)c.name2)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                        columns.Add().Titled("Name3").RenderValueAs(c => Name3((int)c.name3)).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).Filterable(true).WithMultipleFilters()
```

---

Use Inspect element in google chrome(Select the Grid Title bar and click  right button and use inspect element).If it shows the classes in the following image, then the problem is due to either css or js.That mean class names is started with "grid-" and check whether the grid-filter-btn is rendered in the DOM

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that still hasn't fixed the problem. None of the columns are filterable and the ones that are using .RenderValueAs aren't sortable either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you added the gridmvc.css and gridmvc.js files

Comment: Yes, I have these added to the project

Comment: Whether it shows the filter button ?Please explain your problem in detail,(Use inspect element in google chrome)

Comment: Ok, so the filter button isn't visible on the grid at all. I have tried inspecting the element and the grid-filter-btn is rendered in the DOM. I have also tried removing all styling from the Grid while inspecting the element and I can't see the filter button underneath any styling or anything like that either.

Comment: You have added the bootstrap css file?

Comment: I am using bootstrap.css in the project as well, yes.

Comment: You can remove the gridmvc.css reference from the layout

Comment: I should remove the gridmvc.css reference from the layout if I am using bootstrap.css?

Comment: @VipinRT First Thing, you have added 6 columns in your view and in screenshot it has only5 columns  means its not the correct one.  and second point is show the screenshot with filter on 3,4 and 5 column as they are customize not 1,2 and 3

Comment: Surely it works ! this is the right solution . And should Accept as answer.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was adding :

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to the ***head*** section

and

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")
```

to the ***body*** section

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

> The filter is not showing because you have 2 .css files in your project

1) site.css

2) Gridmvc.css

In site.css this is style for a:link which get executed when ever your click on filter icon of Grid.MVC .

You can just remove or commet this lines then you can see Filter is working

```
   th a
    {       
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }

    th a:link, th a:visited, th a:active, th a:hover
    {
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    th a:hover
    {
        color: #000;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filter popup was not showing, sorting worked. When I commented out this section in _layout.cshtml "@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)" filtering worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case filtering didn't work, because I had styles conflict. When I removed @section, and used just @Styles (see below), filtering started to work.

```
@* commented because of styles conflict
    @section styles{
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/Gridmvc")
    }*@

@Styles.Render("~/Content/Gridmvc")

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Gridmvc")
}
```

I'm attaching link to simplified solution on github:
https://github.com/sam-klok/WebAppGrid